# ISP Manager 5 API не получается запретить настройки пользователя

Tags: api, запрос, ispmanager

Есть к примеру запрос на создание пользователя, но нужно чтобы при создании у него не было прав изменять настройки своего аккаунта (пароль например)

```
"https://1.1.1.1:1500/ispmgr?authinfo=".$login.":".$passw."&out=xml&func=user.edit&sok=yes&name=".$user."&fullname=".$fullname."&passwd=".$userpass."&confirm=".$userpass."&preset=Green-".$item_name."&func=user.access.disable&elid=usrparam"
```

Пользователь создается, но запрета на настройки у него нет, может я не правильно записал функцию **user.access.disable**?

Answer (score -1):

Здравствуйте. 
Одним запросом по API не обойтись. Нужно сначала создать пользователя по API, а потом уже другим запросом отключать ему права - функция userrights.fields

Как правильно создать запрос по API можно прочитать в нашей документации
[https://doc.ispsystem.ru/index.php/Взаимодействие_через_API](https://doc.ispsystem.ru/index.php/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_API)

Если будут вопросы, можете обращаться в поддержку ISPsystem через личный кабинет на сайте ispsystem.ru